# OpenShift : error while copying from local window 7 machine to openshift

Tags: cloud, openshift

I am tyring to copy a zipfile from my windows 7 machine using command line to a directory on Openshift with following command.

```
rhc scp <app> upload C:\adf-essentials.zip @<app>-<domain_name>.rhcloud.com:/var/lib/openshift/<userid>/app-root/runtime/repo/diy/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib
```

its throwing following error.

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
uploading C:\adf-essentials.zip: 0% complete. 0/217544
72 bytes transferred An unknown error occurred: SCP did not finish successfully
(1):
```

please can you help resolving this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format for that command is:

```
rhc scp <app> upload C:\adf-essentials.zip app-root/runtime/repo/diy/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib
```